# C++ socket client to python server no connection created

Tags: c++, sockets, stream-socket-client

I am trying to create C++ socket client for python server.
Because I am new to C++ before creating the C++ client I checked if the python socket server with python client. After creating and running the C++ client the server do not get any connection

server.py

```py
def start_listener():
    ip = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 4444
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        # Tying to bind
        server.bind((ip, port))
        server.listen(3)
        print("[+] Server bind on %s:%d" %(ip,port))
    except socket.error as error:
        print("[!] Unable to bind on %s:%d" %(ip,port))

    # Waiting for connections and handle them
    while True:
            print("Wating for connections...")
            # Waiting part
            connenction, addr = server.accept()
            print("[+] Accecpted connection from %s:%d" % (addr[0],addr[1]))
            data = connenction.recv(2000).decode()
            print(data)

start_listener()
```

ClientSocket.cpp:

```cpp
#include "ClientSocket.h"
#include <iostream>

ClientSocket::ClientSocket(string ip, int port) {
    socket_ip = ip;
    socket_port = port;
}

void ClientSocket::CreateSession(){
    ClientSocket::sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(ClientSocket::sock < 0){
        cout << "[!] Unable to create socket" << endl;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr((ClientSocket::socket_ip).c_str());
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(ClientSocket::socket_port);

    if(connect(ClientSocket::sock, (SOCKADDR *)&serv_addr ,sizeof(sockaddr)) < 0){
        cout << "[!] Unable to connect to remote socket" << endl;
    }
}
```

ClientSocket.h

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

using namespace std;

#ifndef SOCKET_H
#define SOCKET_H

class ClientSocket {
    private:
        string socket_ip;
        int socket_port;
        SOCKET sock;
    public:
        ClientSocket(string ip, int port);
        void PrintSocket();
        void CreateSession();
        void SendData(string data);
};

#endif // SOCKET_H
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "ClientSocket.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ClientSocket clientsocket ("127.0.0.1", 4444);
    clientsocket.CreateSession();
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
[!] Unable to connect to remote socket
```

After including `<errno.h>` and print the error its print no error

Comment: Can you add the python server code?

Comment: I added the python server code @HenryLeBerre

Comment: Thanks but the c++ doesn't link fo me... but try chaning the ip in the python file to "127.0.0.1"

Comment: @GiladDiCastro: Just to be sure: client and server run on the same physical and logical machine (i.e. not on different VM etc)? Also, please provide the actual error reasons, i.e. use WSAGetLastError. And did you try it with a small Python client since you are more familiar with this?

Comment: Yes but it should be possible if the network adapter for your vm is set properly.

Comment: @HenryLeBerre the 0.0.0.0 should not get any connection from all ips?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich they are on the same vm

Comment: You are right, just checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
WSADATA wsaData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData);
```

before creating the client socket to [initialize winsock2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/initializing-winsock)

So it should look like this:

```
void CreateSession() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData);
    this->sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (this->sock < 0) {
        cout << "[!] Unable to create socket" << endl;
    }
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr((ClientSocket::socket_ip).c_str());
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(ClientSocket::socket_port);

    if (connect(this->sock, (SOCKADDR*)&serv_addr, sizeof(sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "[!] Unable to connect to remote socket" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: After adding the code now the client "enable to create connection" but in server side he say his not get any connections

Comment: It works for me, verify that you are linking with the right version of winsock with "#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")" (it might have something to do with it, idk)

Comment: why the server print error after connection close by force from client side? it is relate to the WSAStartup?

Comment: The server prints an error when the connection is closed by force from the client because it is trying to receive data from a no longer existing connection.